# Date Time Calculations C#

Tags: c#, datetime, text-files

I am looking to report the percentage of run time of a machine. I need year to date,last two weeks, yesterday,and today's percentage of run time. I don't want to start this off going the wrong direction so I need some advice. My data looks like this in a text file.

```
10/21/2014 07:45:31,ON
10/21/2014 07:45:41,OFF
10/21/2014 07:46:11,ON
10/21/2014 07:46:21,OFF
10/21/2014 07:46:41,ON
10/21/2014 07:46:51,OFF
10/21/2014 07:47:12,ON
10/21/2014 07:47:22,OFF
10/21/2014 14:17:35,ON
10/21/2014 14:17:55,OFF
10/21/2014 14:18:25,ON
10/21/2014 14:18:35,OFF
10/21/2014 15:51:21,ON
10/21/2014 15:51:51,OFF
10/21/2014 15:53:01,ON
10/21/2014 15:58:22,OFF
10/21/2014 15:58:32,ON
10/21/2014 16:12:33,OFF
10/21/2014 16:12:42,ON
10/21/2014 16:16:33,OFF
10/21/2014 16:16:43,ON
```

I plan to write this in C#. My thoughts were to calculate this using c# and write this data to another comma delimited text file that I could bring into excel. I have done this in excel but it is painfully slow and I will have a years worth of data to crunch.
I hope to eventually bypass excel and code my graphs.
If you see a better way, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: TimeSpan would be the best option.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: is there one source file or something like one per date?

Comment: Is there a question in here somewhere? Are you asking how to parse the file? How to compute the number of hours/minutes/seconds a machine was ON in a particular day? How to write the result to a text file? You've told us what your data looks like, and vaguely what you want to do with it. Have you tried anything? Give us *specific* questions.

Answer (score 0):

A little example that might point you into a direction:

```
// Get all the lines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("myfile.txt");

// Create a list of OnPeriods (see below) which then can be used for statistics
var onPeriods = new List<OnPeriod>();

// Make sure we're starting with an 'ON' line, otherwise ignore the first line and take the 2nd
var start = lines[0].Contains("ON") ? 0 : 1;

for (int i = start; i < lines.Count(); i = i+2)
{
    // Parse out datetimes
    var dateOn = DateTime.Parse(lines[i].Split(',')[0]);
    var dateOff = DateTime.Parse(lines[i + 1].Split(',')[0]);

    // Add period
    onPeriods.Add(new OnPeriod{OnDate = dateOn, OffDate = dateOff});
}

// Now you can do all kind of magic like
var secondsOnInTheLastTwoWeeks = onPeriods.Where(p => p.OnDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)).Select(p => p.OnTime.Seconds).Sum();
```

For that you would need the little helper class OnPeriod:

```
public class OnPeriod
{
    public DateTime OnDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime OffDate { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan OnTime {get { return OffDate.Subtract(OnDate); }}
}
```

**UPDATE**
This is obviously not very precise since you could have a period that has already started before the comparison date (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-14)) and ended after it. But I'm sure you're going to figure that out by yourself.

Comment: What happens to your code if there are two consecutive "ON" lines, or two consecutive "OFF" lines? Do you think that's a reasonable possibility that you should make allowances for?

Comment: I have no idea how 'clean' the file is. If that possibility exist then it obviously gets more complex. The example data provided does not show these cases though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data will always be in chronological order and starts with "ON" and ends with "OFF"....here's some pretty simple code that will get the job done.

(I didn't actually read it from a file, you can implement that however you want)

```
string[] times = {  "10/21/2014 07:45:31,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 07:45:41,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 07:46:11,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 07:46:21,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 07:46:41,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 07:46:51,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 07:47:12,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 07:47:22,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 14:17:35,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 14:17:55,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 14:18:25,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 14:18:35,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 15:51:21,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 15:51:51,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 15:53:01,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 15:58:22,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 15:58:32,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 16:12:33,OFF",
                    "10/21/2014 16:12:42,ON",
                    "10/21/2014 16:16:33,OFF"
                };   

TimeSpan upTime = new TimeSpan();         

for (int i = 0; i < times.Length; i += 2)
{
    var start = times[i].Split(',');
    var stop = times[i + 1].Split(',');

    upTime += DateTime.Parse(stop[0]) - DateTime.Parse(start[0]);
}

var begin = DateTime.Parse(times.First().Split(',')[0]);
var end = DateTime.Parse(times.Last().Split(',')[0]);
var totalTime = end - begin;
var percentUp = upTime.TotalSeconds / totalTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of data you can import them into sql server table.
Create a view of who displays relevant statistics.
To view on SQL server could connect to directly from excel.
In this way, can store the data in one place and will avoid processing files.